# How to change the default date interval in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am not sure what is the default date interval in ggplot. My data has five data points including Sep-2011, Dec-2011, Mar-2012,Jun-2012 and Sep-2012.

The ggplot displays different data points from my data which I found a bit annoying. Am I missing anything?

Could you help to display "Sep-2011, Dec-2011, Mar-2012,Jun-2012 and Sep-2012

```
x4.1.m<- structure(list(Var.1=structure(c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L),.Label=c("I'vechangedforwork/anewjob/goneonaworkplan","IwantaphonethatVodafonedoesn'toffer","IwantBestMates/Favourites","Iwasofferedorsawabetterofferonanothernetwork","Issueswiththe2degreesnetwork(poorcoverage)","Other"),class="factor"),YearQuarter=structure(c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,4L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L,5L),.Label=c("2011-09-01","2011-12-01","2012-03-01","2012-06-01","2012-09-01"),class="factor"),value=c(0.23,0.23,0.121,0.25,0.223,0.14,0.39,0.22,0.05,0.37,0.25,0.2,0.09,0.14,0.05,0.3,0.4,0.12,0.13,0.1,0.26,0.38,0.28,0.15,0.33,0.05,0.06,0.44,0.32,0.43)),.Names=c("Var.1","YearQuarter","value"),row.names=c(NA,-30L),class="data.frame")

library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
###data 
x4.1.m$YearQuarter <- as.Date(x4.1.m$YearQuarter)
x4.1.m$label       <- paste(round(x4.1.m$value*100,0), "%", sep="")

### plot
x4.line <- ggplot(data=x4.1.m, aes(x=YearQuarter, y=value,colour=Var.1)) +
        geom_smooth(se=F, size=1.5)
x4.line <- x4.line + geom_text(aes(label = label),size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust =1.5) 

### theme  
x4.line <- x4.line +  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
       panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
       panel.background=element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
       panel.border = element_blank()) 

x4.line <- x4.line +  ggtitle("Percentages:Main Reasons for Leaving Vodafone by Quarter") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=rel(1.2)))+ 
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0,0.5)) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"),breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))+
  labs(y="Percentage",x="Year Quarter")

x4.line
```

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation for `scale_x_date` a function you appear to already know of. Notice it has a breaks argument.

Comment: I suggest like @joran that you invest a little bit to learn R and ggplot2, we are not here to do your job.  I wrote this code for you in a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692739/how-to-display-data-in-sep-12-format-in-a-line-chart-and-suppress-the-gridlines/13693472#13693472 The mimimum is to understand it!

Comment: I just switched to R 2.15.2 and the latest version of ggplot. I found it confused with the changes.if I am as clever as you are, I wouldn't have asked the question? Thanks for your previous response. However, you graph didn't show the sequence I wanted...hence I asked this question.
Have a think when you were first learning R. How many times you stuck with little questions? hehe.....

Comment: I think the point people are trying to make is that it appears as if you are putting very little effort into researching or solving problems yourself, before asking on SO. So, in this case, that would have meant reading `?scale_x_date` and making an attempt to do what is clearly described under the breaks argument. If it _still_ doesn't work, then ask and explain what you're tried.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass your required breaks to  `breaks` argument to `scale_x_date` (what a surprise there.)

```
# your breaks 
d <- unique(x4.1.m[['YearQuarter']])
themestuff <-  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                        panel.background=element_blank(),
                        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                        panel.border = element_blank())  

x4.line <- ggplot(data=x4.1.m, aes(x=YearQuarter, y=value,colour=Var.1)) +
 geom_smooth(se=F, size=1.5) + 
 geom_text(aes(label = label),size = 3, hjust = 0.5, vjust =1.5) +
 themestuff +  ggtitle("Percentages:Main Reasons for Leaving Vodafone by Quarter") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(size=rel(1.2))) +
 scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0,0.5)) +
 scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"), breaks = d)+
 labs(y="Percentage",x="Year Quarter")
x4.line
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. 
Can I not just get ggplot to read the dates from table x4.1.m?
This seems to be very manual.

Comment: How about you use a bit of initiative.